# Reducing the Amount of Casts on a View

Tags: android

I can't seem to figure out how to write this code more efficiently. I'm iterating through views to check validity (text entered) but i find myself casting way too much. According to eclipse i need to cast in order to access the methods on the view. Here's the code:

```
// Verify Drivers/Vehicles Entered
private boolean checkDriversVehiclesValidity() {
    int viewCount = mContainerView.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
        View v = mContainerView.getChildAt(i);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.driverVehicleRow) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ((LinearLayout) v).getChildCount(); j++) {
                View v1 = ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(j);
                if (v1 instanceof CustomAutoCompleteTextView) {
                    if (((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v1).getError() != null) {
                        v1.requestFocus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (v1.getId() == R.id.drivers_field) {
                        String driverNumber = ((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v1).getText().toString();
                        if ("".equals(driverNumber)) {
                            ((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v1).setError("Driver required");
                            v1.requestFocus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (v1.getId() == R.id.vehicles_field) {
                        String vehicleNumber = ((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v1).getText().toString();
                        if ("".equals(vehicleNumber)) {
                            ((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v1).setError("Vehicle required");
                            v1.requestFocus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, after checking for

```
if (v1 instanceof CustomAutoCompleteTextView)
```

you can be sure it IS an instance of `CustomAutoCompleteTextView`, so you can assign it to a properly typed variable like this:

CustomAutoCompleteTextView cv = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView)v1;

and use `cv` instead of `((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) v1)` later.